# Would the Wi-Fi reception improve by replacing the factory Wi-Fi card?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Samsung series 9 laptop and even though it's considered to be an "ultrabook" it's Wi-Fi performance is annoyingly poor compared to other laptops I've used on the same networks. Can I improve this performance by getting a better Wi-Fi card? Or should I get a new antenna instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "reception" I'm assuming that you mean Received Signal Strength. This is determined by many factors, including your wifi cards antenna. Some cards are generally better at coping with poor signal quality, so a replacement might be an option. Additionally, if the new card comes with a better antenna, this would increase the Signal to Noise ratio (SNR), thus providing a better end-result.

Comment: Thanks. What about compatibility?

Comment: @Reza Compatibility either exists or doesn't. You'd need to be more specific! The thing to do is to look up the specs of your laptop - or simply open it up and see - for whether it has a replaceable wi-fi card (probably), what interface it uses, and how far you can upgrade it (I'm not well-versed on whether you can just put _anything_ in, but I slightly doubt it).

Comment: @Reza This is mini PCIe. It is supposed to work. Though, great care must be taken because some laptop manufacturers add a limited set of FCC IDs of WLAN cards to their firmware. If you don't have one, the device won't boot.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's entirely possible that a given laptop's WiFi subsystem is poor, and that a good USB WiFi dongle can outperform it.

Comment: worth noting there are usb wifi modules with an antenna which apparently helps with poor signal situation